# Why does my ASP.NET Web API validation code sometimes return unexpected results?

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-web-api

I have the problem while i try to check user existence

So, i wanna check if user already exist or not and have implemented such logic there

```
[HttpPost("Create")]
        [Authorize(Policy = "OnlyAdmin")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<User>> Register
            ([FromBody] SenderCredentials sender, [FromQuery] UserDto request)
        {
            if (await _validator.isUserExist(request.Login) == true)
            {
                return BadRequest($"User {request.Login} alreay exist");
            }
            if (await _validator.isUserExist(sender.SenderLogin) == false)
            {
                return BadRequest($"User {sender.SenderLogin} doesen't exist");
            }
            var newUser = _mapper.Map<User>(request);
            newUser.Birthday = request.Birthday;
            newUser.Gender = request.Gender;
            newUser.IsAdmin = request.IsAdmin;
            newUser.Name = request.Name;
            newUser.CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
            newUser.CreatedBy = sender.SenderLogin;
            /*await  _userContext.Users.AddAsync(newUser);
            await _userContext.SaveChangesAsync();*/
            return Ok(newUser);
        }
```

Validator is just service i've created for my validation with single method

```
 public async Task<bool> isUserExist(string login)
    {
        var user = await _userContext.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Login == login);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

And problem is that when i toggle this endpoint in swagger it returns me result with uncontrolled behaviour. I put in swagger's request fields same data every request and every time this does differently.
When i try it with debugger and  break points this do well, when just debugger but without breakpoints this do well for a while but after several attempts it returns me 200 status code without any response body, sometimes it returns me 400 status code but without message.
When i try it without debugger first time it cann return what i need, but next times it returns 200 status code.
Firstly i have tried do this stuff with filters and attributes but had same problem,i thought that
problem was in such approcah but isn't.
[Here is my repository](https://github.com/DIDIVERG/test)
Will be appreciate if somebody help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you are describing, it makes me think about [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). Oftentimes, when things work during debugging 100% of the time, but not during live testing, it means things are accessing stuff before they should. Also, the two different responses with the same info point me to this. Parallel computing with tasks and threads can result in the accessing of a resource at the same time or out of sequence, which is the essence of race conditions.

I would consider looking into what each thread is doing, possibly by logging timestamps to a file whenever you do something with a description of what the task is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was in my middleware, i forgot to await "next" delegate when i check database existence in it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).